# Issue with title for image in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

am having the following code, in which the title is not displaying totally when putting cursor on it, if title is given as "The Value", the title is shown only as only "The" and not "The Value". Can someone let me know whats the mistake.Please.

```
var str1 = "The Value";
var str;
if (str1.length > 10) {
                        str = str1.substring(0, 10);
                        str = str + "...";
                    }

<li><div id=' + itemId + ' class="append_content" title=' + str1 + '><div class="append_pic"><img style="width:54px; height:54px;" src='+icon+'></div><div class="append_text">' + str + '</div></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking the proper encapsulation for your attribute definitions. It is required to write `="'+ variable+'"` if the `variable` contains spaces. Please observe:

```
title=' + str1 +'
```

should be

```
title="'+ str1 +'"
```

and you should do this for all other attributes, as well.

Comment: thank you so much. its working. as it is a variable, i thought "" not necessary

Comment: one more doubt can i ask you